# Fetch product data by referenceContainer in product list page

Tags: magento2, layout, price, containers

I need to hide product price in product list page. By below code, I can hide price but I need some product data for condition.
I have read that **$block** variable is available in block but I am using container because I don't want to edit/change whole page.

Please help.

My layout xml file is : **catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Prince_Callforprice::css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Prince\Callforprice\Block\Show" name="remove_price_and_addtocart_search_list" template="Prince_Callforprice::product/list/remove_price.phtml" cacheable="false" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

My phtml file is : **remove_price.phtml**

```
<?php

$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); // error comes here

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){ ?>
 <!-- product data -->
<?php } ?>

<?php  if($block->isCallforpriceEnable()){ 
      $btnLabel = 'Call For Price';
?>
 <script>
 var label = '<?php echo $btnLabel; ?>';
   require([
        "jquery",
   ], function($){
        var closeTags = $('.solcfpspan');
        $.each(closeTags,function(index,value){
          var closeButton = '<a href="#" class="fancybox action primary">'+label+'</a>';
            if($(this).parent().find('.product-item-inner .actions-primary')){ 
                $(this).parent().find('.product-item-inner .actions-primary').html(closeButton);
            }
            if($(this).parent().find('.product-item-actions .actions-primary')){
                $(this).parent().find('.product-item-actions .actions-primary').html(closeButton);
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

**[EDIT]**

My **Show.php** file is:

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Callforprice\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;

class Show extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_helper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Prince\Callforprice\Helper\Data $helper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}    

public function getLabel()
{
    return $this->_helper->getConfigValue('callforpricesection/callforpricegroup/callforpricebuttontext');
}

public function isCallforpriceEnable()
{
    return $this->_helper->getConfigValue('callforpricesection/callforpricegroup/active');
}   
}
```

It gives fatat error:
**"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:13450:"#0 /214fresh/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()**

Answer (score 1):

your block class should be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Prince\Callforprice\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;

class Show extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
            $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
            $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
            $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $postDataHelper,
                $layerResolver,
                $categoryRepository,
                $urlHelper,
                $data
            );
        }
    public function isCallforpriceEnable(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sarafaraz, I have updated my question. After your code, it give me fatal error.

Comment: You have extended : \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Please extend this: \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Comment: also declare remaining protected variables

Comment: @Sarfarazbheda please help 

[link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172194/update-programtically-created-product) ,

[link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172566/ajax-validation-for-login-form) , 

[link3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172183/create-product-after-user-loggedin)