# Ajax validation for login form

Tags: magento-1.9

once we click on login "button" , we are hiding the pop up , but we want to hide only if the login is successfull. [ if customer enter valid email id & password ]

controllers

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }
            // echo $login['product_id'];die;
            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());


                    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();
                    // To save inside my_designs

                    return $product;                   

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);

                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();
                    /
                }
            // } else {
            //     $result['error'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Login and password are required.');
            // }
        // }

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

        // code for guest end
    }
```

Login Form

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect.....>

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" />
<label>password</label>
<input type="password" name="login[password]"  id="pass" />

<button onclick="hideWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to edit the function `hideWindow()` in your javascript files to check if the login is succesfull.

And I presume that your login function is called by ajax? If so, return a value back to the login modal that the user is logged in or not and then check on this value if the modal should be closed or not.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect.....>

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" />
<label>password</label>
<input type="password" name="login[password]"  id="pass" />

<button onclick="hideWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
</form>
<input type=hidden id=loggedin value={true/false} />
```

As listed above: `<input type=hidden id=loggedin value={true/false} />` the value attribute should contain the returned value of the ajax function.

if you're using jquery

```
function hideWindow() {
    var isLoggedin = jQuery('#loggedin').val();
    if (isLoggedin) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: now, its not hiding the pop up for wrong email / password, but even its not hiding if we enter correct email and password also....

Comment: i have this code : `function hideWindow() 

{ 

var isLoggedin = jQuery('#loggedin').value();
    if (isLoggedin) {

document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'none'; 

document.getElementById('ajaxlogin-mask').style.display = 'none';
 }

 }`

Comment: I've made a code error it should be: `.val()` instead of `.value()`. Also did you return the value to the new added input field? which should be either true or false?

Comment: i got `{"ok":false}` under `network` tab

Comment: @vickeycolors you are running more then once the function hideWindow() on your site. This is probably conflicting with each other. also i edited my answer.

Comment: sorry for that, we were using one `hideWindow()` for login and one for register, now i renamed one `hidewindow` to `hidewindow1`. i checked this line `<input type=hidden id=loggedin value={true/false} />` , but i a, getting result as `false` in network tab.....

Comment: Just to clarify: `{true/false}` shouldnt be in the code. It is just a refrence to what the login response could be; either true or false.

Comment: sorry for that, can you please help me to find what is the correct code to replace true/false....

Comment: I'll look into it, i'll reply if i found your problem. One more question: is this login modal you're using a third party extension or something you build yourself?

Comment: One more question: is this login modal you're using a third party extension or something you build yourself?

Comment: its are 3 party extension, but if you want any details, please let me know so that i will find it.....

Comment: What is the name of the login modal extension?

Comment: extension name :  `ProductLike` , but i didt found in online as it is installed by previous developer.....

Comment: Mhh unfortunate, it will make the problem a bit more difficult to fix. But my guesses would be that you need to edit this module. The function you mentioned before (`_createProduct`), is this extended from the original function?

Comment: we are using another module for creating product , please check http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Comment: Alright so, as far as i can understand is that the login modal is not related to the module creating the product?

Comment: yes, right, both are different, different modules for ajax login and different one for creating product.....

Comment: You need to look into the login module instead of the module to create the product. So you should look into the function that is run when you try to login. If the credentials are correct or incorrect it should return a value. In the ajax complete function (jquery, javascript or however it is activated) your should return the value to the newly added input.

Comment: once we click on `login` we are submitting a `form` ,  `<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect` so i thought we need to validation in this controller action....

Comment: also validation is working fine once i remove `onclick="hideWindow()"`

Comment: Removing the onclick was my second guess but that is not really what you asked. :). Will the removing do what you wanted?

Comment: I need 2 things here 1) validation after click on login 2)remove/hide pop up after click on `login` , both will work individually for some code, but both will not work.....

Comment: Can you actually login using that login modal? Or is this something that should be created still?

Comment: everything is working fine with login model  [ yes, i can login ]  ..... only requirement is achieveing both of above ......

Comment: I send you a email :).

Comment: okay, so i neeed to try to hide the pop up with help of php function instead of javascript function ?

Comment: Reply to email :).

Comment: if email & pw are correct, than under `Response` tab, it dont display any message, but if credentials are wrong than it will display message as `
{"success":false,"error":"Invalid login or password."}` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0eBY.png ,  is it possible to hide pop up based on Response text ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If you can locate the function that puts this message in the console, edit this to hide the popup. something like: if message is empty then hide ;)

Comment: @vickey: could you join this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58247/kidsdial